# How would I go about re-writing a file so that it may become more manageable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem Is that I am trying to write code so that my .txt file will be re-written into a more manageable version of itself. The 'program' needs to read seven lines at a time and then write it out as a single line in another .txt file then repeat this function until it has gone through the entire .txt file.

I have been looking all over the internet and have tried multiple things however none of it even comes close to what I need the closest I've gotten is with the following code.

```
first_line = 7

def function():

    with open ('file_txt', 'r') as read_file1:

            line = [next(read_file1) for x in range(first_line)]

            with open ('file_txt_new', 'w') as write_file2:

                    write_file2.write(str(line))
```

The input text file looks like this:

```
Awakened Shrub
Small plant, unaligned
Hit Points:
10 (3d6) Armor Class:
9 Speed:
20 ft. Challenge Rating:
0 (10 XP)
```

expected results: these results are simply the original text file being       re-writen in a single line.

example 1: This would be written on line one of the new text document.

```
Awakened Shrub, Small plant, unaligned, Hit Points: 10 (3d6) Armour Class: 9
```

example 2: This would be written on line two of the new text document.

```
Baboon, Small beast, unaligned, Hit Points: 1 (1d4 - 1) Armour Class: 9
```

actual results:

```
['Awakened Shrub\n', 'Small plant, unaligned\n', 'baboon\n', 'Small beast, unaligned\n',]
```

Comment: What does your input text file look like?

Comment: Why would your expected results only put two lines into a single output line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code helps you:

```
num_reads = 7
with open('data.txt') as read_file:
    with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as write_file:

        while (True):
            lines = []
            try:       # You should expect errors if the number of lines in the file are not a multiplication of num_reads
                for i in range(num_reads):     
                    lines.append(next(read_file))  # when the file finishes an exception occurs here

                #do sutff with the lines (exactly num_reads number of lines)
                processed = " ".join(list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", ''), lines)))
                write_file.write(processed + '\n')

            except StopIteration:     # here we process the (possibly) insufficent last lines
                #do stuff with the lines (less that  num_reads)
                processed = " ".join(list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", ''), lines)))
                write_file.write(processed + '\n')
                break
```

When the end of file is reached a `StopIteration` error is raised and caught by `except` where you can process the possible insufficient lines of data captured and break out of the `while` loop. In the above piece of code, I did the same operation on both full (num_reads = 7) captures and the partial ones. The processing part just attaches the lines and removes newline characters.
When `data.txt` is like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
```

`new_data.txt` will be like this:

```
line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6 line7
line8 line9 line10
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda` is basically the defining reason Guido wanted to get rid of `map`. Just use a listcomp; it's faster, shorter and clearer than any equivalent `map` that has to use a Python level function to work, e.g. `" ".join([x.rstrip('\n') for x in lines])`. Also, pretty sure you want `write` in both cases; `writelines` works (a `str` is an iterable of length 1 `str`s), but it's pointless with a single `str`.

Comment: @Shadow. You probably wouldn't want the square brackets there if you're worried about overhead.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Dirty knowledge here, but as an implementation detail, CPython's `str.join` converts any non-`tuple`, non-`list` input to a `list` (via `PySequence_Fast`) before it begins joining at all; `list`ifying a genexpr is more expensive than using a listcomp directly.

Comment: @Shadow Excellent point. It's got to compute the size of the full string somehow and then make another pass. TIL.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is making `list`s, but to do what you want, you need to put them back together into a single string (`str(line)` doesn't do it, because that just produces the string representation of a `list`; you need `str.join`):

```
first_line = 7

def function():
    # Open output file once up front (or you'll replace it for each new set of seven lines)
    with open('file_txt', 'r') as read_file1, open('file_txt_new', 'w') as write_file2:
        while True:
            # Get the lines, providing a default value to next in case you run out of lines
            lines = [next(read_file1, '') for x in range(first_line)]
            # Convert to a single string, and replace newlines with `, ` matching expected output
            newline = ''.join(lines).rstrip('\n').replace('\n', ', ')
            # Got nothing but empty lines, must have exhausted file, so we're done
            if not newline:
                break
            write_file2.write(newline + "\n")
```

Note: You could slightly simplify/speed up your code using `itertools.islice`, assuming you're allowed to import modules, replacing:

```
            lines = [next(read_file1, '') for x in range(first_line)]
```

with:

```
            lines = itertools.islice(read_file1, first_line)
```

Comment: How does `rstrip('\n').replace('\n', ', ')` work? I feel like maybe you meant just one or the other. Since you're joining with `''`, `rstrip` is probably extra.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The final newline needs to go away completely, or every combined line would end with `', '` (which you only want within the line to separate components, not at the end).

Comment: I totally misread that line. You're stripping the result of the join. Time to sleep, and +1 for you of course